# PHP returns true for all files that are run thru if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, substr

I'm totally stumped. I have a array holding all the files in a directory on my website. I use an `if` statement within a `foreach` loop to filter the results. If the file name begins with a certain combination of three letters `("wwa" or "wea" or "swa" or "hta" or "cta" or "twa" or "fra")` then that file name is assigned to `$alert_string`.

For some reason, all of the files return `true` inside the if statement, so the variable is simply overwritten each time, and the last file scanned is assigned the variable.

Code:

```
   $alert_files = scandir("/home/prww/public_html/blog/");

   foreach ($alert_files as $values) {
        if ((substr($values, 0, 3)) == ("wwa" or "wea" or "swa" or "hta" or "cta" or "twa" or "fra")) {
            $alert_string = $values;
        }
    }
```

Files in the directory:

[image: Files in the directory]

Clearly, only the file beginning with "hta" should return true in the if statement. So why does every file return true and how can I fix this?

Comment: Because you cannot do an "or" statement that way. You have to test each condition like `if (substr($values, 0, 3)) == "wwa" OR substr($values, 0, 3)) == "wea"` etc.

Comment: This is wrong syntax. Please refer to manual or documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if syntax is wrong.
You can simplify the logic using an array:

```
//array of allowed substrings, used as index for quicker lookup
$substringKeys = array_flip(["wwa","wea","swa","hta","cta","twa","fra"]);

$alert_string='';

$alert_files = scandir("/home/prww/public_html/blog/");

foreach ($alert_files as $filename) {
    $substr = substr($filename, 0, 3);
    if (isset($substringkeys[$substr])) {
        //add to, not overwrite, $alert_string
        $alert_string .= $values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
("wwa" or "wea" or "swa" or "hta" or "cta" or "twa" or "fra")
```

yields a boolean TRUE. As long as `substr($values, 0, 3)` returns something, your conditional expression will always be TRUE.

You can't write code that looks like it makes sense in English without understanding how the operators actually work. And when all else fails, `echo` intermediate results so you can understand what your program is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function to achieve this with help for `array_map`

```
$alert_files = scandir("/home/prww/public_html/blog/");

$fileNames = array_filter(array_map("checkName",$alert_files));
print_r($fileNames);

function checkName($fileName)
{
    $file = substr($fileName,0,3);
    $conditionArray = array("wwa","wea","swa","hta","cta","twa","fra");
    if(in_array($file,$conditionArray))
    {
        return $fileName;
    }
}
```